# Regarding Bash substring comparison

Tags: bash

I try to test if a string starts with a certain prefix. But my script seems not work (I would expect the "if" branch will not get run). Can some Bash expert help to take a look? thanks!

Here is my code and test result:

$ cat testb.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

my_var="abcdefg";
if [[ "${my_var:0:5}"=="order" ]]; then
    echo "value of my_var is ${my_var}.";
fi;

if [[ "${my_var:0:5}" -eq "order" ]]; then
    echo "value of my_var is ${my_var}.";
fi;

if [ "${my_var:0:5}"="order" ]; then
    echo "value of my_var is ${my_var}.";
fi;
```

$ bash -x testb.bash

```
+ my_var=abcdefg
+ [[ -n abcde==order ]]
+ echo 'value of my_var is abcdefg.'            
value of my_var is abcdefg.
+ [[ abcde -eq order ]]
+ echo 'value of my_var is abcdefg.'
value of my_var is abcdefg.
+ '[' abcde=order ']'
+ echo 'value of my_var is abcdefg.'
value of my_var is abcdefg.
$
```

Answer (score 2):

To test the existence of substring, you can use either of these:

```
if [[ "$j" =~ string1 ]]; then
if [[ $j == *string1* ]]; then
```

In your particular case, you miss a space surounding `==`, so instead of

```
if [[ "${my_var:0:5}"=="order" ]]; then
```

it should be

```
if [[ "${my_var:0:5}" == "order" ]]; then
                     ^  ^
```

Finally, note that your condition was evaluated as true because it was evaluating `if [ "string" ]`, which is true if `string` is not empty:

```
$ [ "a" ] && echo "yes"
yes
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash

my_var="abcdefg";
if [[ "${my_var:0:5}" == "order" ]]; then
    echo "value of my_var is ${my_var}."
elif [[ "${my_var:0:5}" == "abcde" ]]; then
    echo "yeahaa"
else
    echo "is not"
fi

$ ./a
yeahaa
```

Comment: Also you can remove useless semicolons

Comment: I guess just from `my_var="abcdefg"`. In the `if` condition they are necessary before `then`.

Comment: You have an eagle-eye, @Aleks-DanielJakimenko :D

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace is significant in this case. As you can see in the `-x` output, it understands the first condition as

```
[[ -n "${my_var:0:5}==order" ]]
```

Moreover, to test for a prefix, you can use a pattern:

```
[[ $my_var == order* ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i tested your code, you shoud such as the following code:

```
prefix="pre_order";
pre="pre_"
len=${#pre}
echo $len
if [[ "${prefix:0:len}" == "blahvlah" ]] ;  then
 echo "dddd"
fi;
```

**Notes:**

1. use == for string comparation
2. for ${} you should initilize a string variable before ${}
3. use len=${#pre} for lenght of string.

Answer (score 0):

A POSIX-compliant way to test for a prefix is to attempt to *remove* the prefix, and compare the result to the original string. If the two are the same, the prefix is not present, the removal fails, and the expression expands to the original string.

```
prefix=foo
string=foobar

if [ "${string#$prefix}" = "$string" ]; then
    printf "$string does not start with $prefix\n"
else
    printf "$string starts with $prefix\n"
fi
```